# make retrieved images into album using php

Tags: php, jquery

I have retrieved images from a folder and using fancybox plugin displayed all the images as picassa view.. only problem is how to bring all the retrieved images into one album. All the images are come one by one, because in while loop. I want all the images into a album. that is, if i have 4 images means, make all 4 into 'profilepic' album, here is my code..

PHP

```
//get all image files with a .jpg extension.
$images = glob($directory . "*.jpg");

//print each file name
foreach($images as $image)
{
echo $image;
?>
<a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="<?php echo $image; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $image; ?>" alt="" />
<?php
//echo "<a class='fancybox' rel='group' href='$image'><img src='$image' alt='' /></a>";
}
?>
```

SCRIPT

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Can you expand more on your question? It is extremely unclear. You `"want to make all the images into like folder"` ? How so? As in display?

Comment: all images are come one by one, because in while loop. I want all the images into a album. that is, if i have 4 images means, make all 4 into 'profilepic' album.

Comment: @ Darren ,I updated my question.. give any suggestion or do u want further more explanation?